# How to instantiate DB object from configuration?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I instantiate Mongo Client as below. It works fine. However I am trying to read the DB name (`primer` here) from the configuration. How do I do that?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.primer   # want to read "primer" string from a variable
coll = db.dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
db_name = 'primer'    
db = getattr(client, db_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to connect to only one database you can specify the dbname while creating the db object itself

dbname = "primer"

db = MongoClient()[dbname]